# Javascript Alert Not Displaying

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Having trouble getting the javascript alert to display from my code behind.

c# - On Button Click

```
if (response != "")
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "AlertPopup", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Day already exists, please edit the existing day');</script>");
    return; 
}
```

This is coming from within an UpdatePanel. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

**EDIT**

Changed to this code, but still no luck:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "AlertPopup", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Day already exists, please edit the existing day');</script>", true);
```

**SOLUTION**

It was loading too many script tags, this code fixed the issue:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "AlertPopup", "alert('Day already exists, please edit the existing day');", true);
```

Comment: Check your HTML with Firebug or Devtools to see what HTML/script is being loaded.

Comment: BTW,  there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: @Michael - Good call it was loading this in the HTML: <script type="text/javascript">
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Day already exists, please edit the existing day');</script>
</script>

Comment: @Will: Ok. I mention that because some people think it's "C#.NET" because of "VB.NET".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's coming from an UpdatePanel, try using the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` static method.

HTH.

Comment: solution found and added to my post